# How to iterate through jQuery elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, syntax

I want to be able to see what's inside the tags that jQuery finds. How come the following doesn't work?

```
 $("div.UIImageBlock_Content.UIImageBlock_ICON_Content").each ( function() {
     alert(($this).html);
 });
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: @gdoron - typo on my part. Too late to edit so I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$this` => `$(this)`
- `.html` => `.html()`

So this should do it:

```
$("div.UIImageBlock_Content.UIImageBlock_ICON_Content").each ( function() {
     alert($(this).html());
 });
```

Note that `html()` function just uses the innerHTML property, so it can be a lot simpler:

```
$("div.UIImageBlock_Content.UIImageBlock_ICON_Content").each ( function() {
     alert(this.innerHTML);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The current element within a jQuery `each` iteration can be accessed via `this` (not `$this`).

There's a small caveat, however: the `this` in a jQuery iteration refers to each element's underlying DOM object, *not* the jQuery object. You can use this code, then:

```
$("div.UIImageBlock_Content.UIImageBlock_ICON_Content").each ( function() {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
});
```

You don't need to build a jQuery object from the raw DOM object on each iteration — an element's inner HTML is already present in the DOM object, and there's no need for extra work.