# JQuery only looking at one DIV ID to get values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code on one of my web pages which hides certain sections of a form which are irrelevant to some users.  However, for some reason now only the selectAttending variable is being bound. I want to pass the values of a text box and two dropdowns but only the value of this dropdown is being passed.  Any suggestions?

```
<html>    
<input class="input-xlarge focused" id="txtName" type="text" >
<select name=selectAttending id=selectAttending>
   <option>Select One...</option>
   <option>Yes</option>
   <option>No</option>
</select>
<select id=selectGender>
   <option selected="selected">Select One...</option>
   <option>Male</option>
   <option>Female</option>
</select>

<script language=javascript>
$("#selectAttending").change(function () {
    if ($('#selectAttending option:selected').text() == "No") {
        $('#ifAttending').hide();
    } else if ($('#selectAttending option:selected').text() == "Yes") {
        $('#ifAttending').show();
    } else {
        $('#ifAttending').show();
    } 
});      
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have multiple HTML elements with the same ID? If so, you need to change them to classes. ID's are inherently supposed to be unique, so if you have multiple elements with the same ID, then JavaScript will only use the first one.

Comment: Evidently the name attribute must be set for each element for it to work properly as well as the ID. I had only set the ID.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selections create a list of elements; when you use a jQuery selection function, e.g. `$`, you will need to iterate through the results if you want to process more than one.  Try using a function like `each`.  See [this S/O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754256/how-to-iterate-through-jquery-elements), and the relevant [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).