# get div id from class and loop the id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How get div id from the same class and loop the id

example

i have try, but just get 1 id result. this my code:

```js
var ids = $('.test').map(function() {
  var resID = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log(resID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="test">A</div>
<div id="2" class="test">B</div>
<div id="3" class="test">C</div>
<div id="4" class="test">D</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate through jQuery elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754256/how-to-iterate-through-jquery-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var ids = $('.test').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('id');
}).get();

console.log(ids)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="test">A</div> 
<div id="2" class="test">B</div>
<div id="3" class="test">C</div>
<div id="4" class="test">D</div>
```

1. Return the value of id so you can get it to array

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery .each

```js
$( ".test" ).each(function( index ) {
     console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).attr('id') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="test">A</div>
<div id="2" class="test">B</div>
<div id="3" class="test">C</div>
<div id="4" class="test">D</div>
```